# Вывод объявлений пользователя из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простая таблица `blog` в базе данных с полями:`id`, `name`, `text`, `image`, `data_pub`.

Например: в таблице `blog` есть пять записей, я вывожу запись под номером три в один блок с верху, как показано на фото ниже.

[image: Пример]

Как мне остальные записи вывести ниже в другой блок, без записи номер три ?

Comment: Я в недоумении от количества плюсов у этого вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table where id <> 3
```

Comment: Ну хоть бы в условии `3` поставили ;)

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо за ответ.